# Copy cell value to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, range, cell

I'm new to VBA and I am trying to copy values from one cell to multiple cells when its value changes.

The value of A2 is constantly changing and when that happens I want that value to be copied to cells C2:C21 (and then eventually to cells D2:D21)

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJZyZ.jpg

So far I wrote this code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   For i = 0 To 19
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AS2")) Is Nothing Then
         Cells(Target.Row + i, 58).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 45).Value
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

but this only copies one single value of A2 to all the cells C2 to C22.

May anyone help me write this code properly?

Comment: Nothing in this code apperas to handle Cell A2, nor C2:C21, nor D2:D21...

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AS2")) Is Nothing Then
        For CurCol = 3 to 4
            For CurRow = 2 to 21
                If Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = Target.Value
                    Exit Sub
                EndIf
            Next CurRow
        Next CurCol
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` before any statement making workbook/worksheet changes and then handling errors to have `Application.EnableEvents = True` run is always a good practice in a `Worksheet_Change` event handler

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're after:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nVals As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("C2:D21")
            nVals = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells)
            If nVals = .Count Then Exit Sub
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            On Error GoTo exitsub
            .Cells(nVals Mod .Rows.Count + 1, IIf(nVals >= .Rows.Count, 2, 1)).Value = Target.Value
        End With
    End If

exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```